# How to display content in a textarea in a node view result on a Drupal 7 site?

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-hooks

i'm a newbie drupal user and i want to use a hook to display some content for a specific node type.
I have a video portal where i use video module of Drupal. I want to display a textarea zone with embed code for my visitors to share the content on their blogs or sites (like youtube or vimeo etc...).
I think i need to write a little module to do that but which hook i need to use to do this action ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If it's something you'll be reusing a lot (on this project or in the future) I'd personally build a custom formatter for it. Custom formats will appear in a fields display settings so if you build a custom formatter module called `share_code` you can just select 'share code' from the display list and it will render it accordingly.

There is a good tutorial on how to build a Facebook link custom formatter here - http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-tutorial-creating-custom-formatters

I've used this to build a Youtube video formatter and Twitter links.

You handle the output using `hook_field_formatter_view`. So just amend the tutorial above to output the fields value in an un-editable text area.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i can't apply 2 formatters for a same field ? My video field is formatted with video player ? I think it is an option to add in the video module but i'm not sure...

Comment: In that case could you edit the video formatters output to include the embed code? The same hook mentioned above should do it.

Comment: I think you are right, i'll try to edit it. I use Octopus Video Durpal distrib, i don't know if you know it. An example here : http://demo.octopusvideo.org/video/drive

Comment: Have a look in video.module and you'll see where the video is output. Simply add your code to this. Start out just adding plain text and add your code in a bit at a time. From a quick look it's line 422 (video_file_embed()).

Comment: i have a good result when i put some code directly in the video template file. It is not very nice but i think it will work :)

Comment: Cool. For future reference that tutorial I posted is really helpful for building your own formats. I've got a nice little library of them I use now.

Comment: Yes this tuto is useful ! I find this module http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters Do you recommand it ?

Comment: I've not seen that before. I build them as good practice but I've done loads now so this might be handy.